# Problems with RecyclerView and CustomAdapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I've written this code for my recycler view, but it doesn't seem to work (it gives to me some errors)... Can someone tell me what I do wrong?

**CustomAdapter.java:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder> {

//Attributi:
private Context context;
private int[] immagineDio;
private String[] nomeDio;

//Costruttori:
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int[] immagineDio, String[] nomeDio){
    this.context = context;
    this.immagineDio = immagineDio;
    this.nomeDio = nomeDio;
}

//Metodi di istanza:
@NonNull
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return CustomViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(immagineDio[position], nomeDio[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return nomeDio.length;
}

}
```

**CustomViewHolder.java:**

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


 ImageView mFlag;
 TextView mName;

 public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
     super(itemView);
     mFlag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     mName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
 }

 //binding data with UI
 void bind(int imageId, String name) {
     mFlag.setImageResource(imageId);
     mName.setText(name);
 } }
```

**ListViewActivity.java:**

```
 public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);


     String[] nomeDei = {"Baldr","Borr","Bragi","Dagr","Dellingr","Eir","Eostre","Forseti","Freya","Freyr","Frigg","Fulla","Gefjun","Gerðr","Gullveig","Heimdallr","Hel","Hermóðr","Höðr","Hœnir","Iðunn","Itreksjóð","Jǫrð","Kvasir","Lóðurr","Lofn","Logi","Lýtir","Máni","Mímir","Móði","Nanna","Njörun","Njörðr","Nótt","Óðr","Rán","Ríg","Sága","Sif","Signe","Sigyn","Sinfjötli","Sjöfn","Skaði","Skirnir","Snotra","Sól","Syn","Thor","Týr","Ullr","Váli","Vár","Ve","Viðarr","Víli","Vör"};
     int[] immagineDei = {
             R.drawable.profilo_baldr, 
             R.drawable.profilo_borr,
             R.drawable.profilo_bragi,
             R.drawable.profilo_dagr,
             R.drawable.profilo_dellingr,
             R.drawable.profilo_eir, 
             R.drawable.profilo_eostre,
             R.drawable.profilo_forseti, 
             R.drawable.profilo_freya, 
             R.drawable.profilo_freyr,
             R.drawable.profilo_frigg,
             R.drawable.profilo_fulla,
             R.drawable.profilo_gefjun,
             R.drawable.profilo_geror,
             R.drawable.profilo_gullveig,
             R.drawable.profilo_heimdallr,
             R.drawable.profilo_hel, 
             R.drawable.profilo_hermoor,
             R.drawable.profilo_hoor,
             R.drawable.profilo_hoenir,
             R.drawable.profilo_iounn,
             R.drawable.profilo_itreksjoo,
             R.drawable.profilo_joro,
             R.drawable.profilo_kvasir,
             R.drawable.profilo_loourr,
             R.drawable.profilo_lofn,
             R.drawable.profilo_logi,
             R.drawable.profilo_lytir,
             R.drawable.profilo_mani,
             R.drawable.profilo_mimir,
             R.drawable.profilo_modi,
             R.drawable.profilo_nanna,
             R.drawable.profilo_njorun,
             R.drawable.profilo_njoror,
             R.drawable.profilo_nott,
             R.drawable.profilo_oor,
             R.drawable.profilo_ran,
             R.drawable.profilo_rig,
             R.drawable.profilo_saga,
             R.drawable.profilo_sif,
             R.drawable.profilo_signe,
             R.drawable.profilo_sigyn,
             R.drawable.profilo_sinfjotli,
             R.drawable.profilo_sjofn,
             R.drawable.profilo_skaoi,
             R.drawable.profilo_skirnir,
             R.drawable.profilo_snotra,
             R.drawable.profilo_sol,
             R.drawable.profilo_syn,
             R.drawable.profilo_thor,
             R.drawable.profilo_tyr,
             R.drawable.profilo_ullr, 
             R.drawable.profilo_vali,
             R.drawable.profilo_var,
             R.drawable.profilo_ve,
             R.drawable.profilo_vidar,
             R.drawable.profilo_vili,
             R.drawable.profilo_vor,
     };

     ListView listViewReference = findViewById(R.id.listView);
     CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, immagineDei, nomeDei);
     listViewReference.setAdapter(customAdapter); //this line gives an error
 } }
```

**listview_layout.xml:**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Where are errorr? Where did you set `Layoutmanager` on `RecyclerView`? Follow some tutorial on `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Give the Error log please

Answer (score 1):

you have used RecyclerView in your XML file and try to getting ListView in Java code file try this

RecyclerView listViewReference = (RecyclerView )findViewById(R.id.listView);

Comment: and add  `Layout Manager` like this:
`listViewReference.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));` If you need reference put it as property in class to control some needed info from `Layout Manager`

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) is a very detailed and good tutorial on how to implement the recyclerview. Please read it for better understanding. Hope it helps.

**Summary:**

**Step 1:** Below is the RecyclerView widget with necessary attributes.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Step 2:** Open build.gradle and add recycler view dependency. **com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:{{latest version}}** and rebuild the project.

**Step 3:** Create your CustomAdapter

**Step 4:** From your activity/fragment:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not used a Layout Manager for the recycler view
[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)